# Github Pages and Godaddy - CNAME error

Tags: github, dns, jekyll, cname

I'm trying to use my Godaddy domain with github pages.

At this moment I've added the CNAME.md file with davidcafor.me
Created a A record to 192.30.252.153 and a CNAME www record to davidcafor.github.io.

But the problem is that davidcafor.me doesn't works.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From here, davidcafor.github.io points to davidcafor.me. Just have to wait DNS replication.

Answer (score 1):

Your DNS records are correct:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> a davidcafor.me
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31777
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;davidcafor.me.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
davidcafor.me.          3600    IN      A       192.30.252.153
```

The issue is that github.io is not configured to respond to that SNI.  You will need to check with your settings in Github to make sure that domain is properly registered.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the file needs to be named just `CNAME`, not `CNAME.md`. Or was it different in 2015?